# How many of them (revisited)

Tags: pronoms, pronoms-interrogatifs

[There is another thread](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/20334/358) which gives the example

> Je me demande combien d'entre eux vont passer les examens aujourd'hui ?

I wanted to add my question as a comment on to one of the answers but I wasn't allowed to because of not enough reputation.

What I was wondering is whether it is also possible to say only "Combien d'eux" rather than "Combien d'entre eux" or is this totally incorrect?
I ask because when I saw the title of the other question, the phrase that immediately sprung to mind was "combien d'eux" - But my French is very rusty and wasn't that good in the first place.

Thanks for any help in bringing my French back to life again!

Answer (score 3):

No, *combien d'eux* cannot be used in place of *combien d'entre-eux*, just like *combien de nous* cannot be used for *combien d'entre nous*.

At best *combien d'eux* might translate "how many from them" like for example in *Tu en veux combien de moi et combien d'eux*, i.e. "how much of it do you want from me and how much from them" but outside such a context, that form would likely be avoided because it is homophone with *combien d'œufs*, "how many eggs"...

Comment: I would pronounce the "f" in "combien d'oeufs"... It may be a mistake, but makes it clear you talk about eggs... :D

Comment: @Random It would definitely be a mispronunciation and anyway wouldn't solve the issue which is not having "eggs" being understood but "them".

Comment: @jlliagre I agree with Random. I must admit I sometimes pronounce /œf/ when plural. Language evolves...

Comment: @Laure Pourquoi pas, mais cette prononciation reste néanmoins très minoritaire (elle n'est d'ailleurs pas mentionnée ici: http://french.stackexchange.com/q/1555/1109 ) et elle ne change rien au fait qu'il n'existe pas de prononciation alternative à « combien d'eux » qui permettrait de différencier cette forme de « combien d'œufs ».

Comment: Pensez-vous que _combien_ tient lieu de quantificateur au pluriel dans le sens de ce qu'on trouve au bas de l'entrée [_entre_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/entre) au TLFi ? (Le _LBU14_ par. 662c 5 dit que sinon _d'eux_ serait rare sauf si précédé d'un numéral ou de _tous_, mais au final je ne sais pas formellement quel cas s'applique quand c'est avec _combien_; c'est présenté dans un contexte de concurrence entre _de_ et _entre_ avec des formes disjointes après préposition ; dans ce contexte on évoque la confusion avec _deux_.).

Comment: Great. Thanks very much for the answer and the explanation!

Comment: @Onaeu. Oui, « combien » ne limite pas les réponses possibles à zéro ou un. Il peut donc être considéré comme un quantificateur désignant une pluralité.